# How to fire vue lifecycle-events for every instance of a component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a vue-component consisting of multiple instances of the same child-component. Some of these child-components are displayed under condition only. My problem is, that when the if-condition turns to false, both the destroyed-methods as well as the beforeDestroy-methods are only called once (for the last child-component which is to be destroyed) but not for every of the mounted child components. Is there any way to change this behaviour and achieve that the destroyed-method is called for every destroyed instance?

I created a fiddle for better understanding: When switching from "Precondition 1" to "Precondition 2 " I would expect that the destroy-method for both, "instance 1" as well as "instance 2" gets fired. But the console shows only conducting the method for instance 2. 
When switching back to "Precondition 1" there is no destroy-event bubbling up at all, but I would expect it to be called for instance 3.

```
Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5chq02zs/2/
```

I also tried changing "destroyed" with "beforeDestroy" or "deactivated", but the outcome remains the same. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add `key="id"` to elements.

```
    <my-component v-if="picked == 'true'" id="1" :key="1">
      instance 1
    </my-component>
    <my-component v-if="picked == 'true'" id="2" :key="2">
      instance 2
    </my-component>
    <my-component v-if="picked == 'false'" id="3" :key="3">
      instance 3
    </my-component>
```

Comment: Really, that's it? Thank you so much, I googled my ass off for hours now...

Comment: I did it too one day ;-) Good luck!